# Substrings in Swift 4

Tags: substring, swift4

I have a url string (fake)

`http://fools.sayers.mine.cs/api/analytics/ces_ssn`

And I'd like to create a new URL string

`http://fools.sayers.mine.cs/api/`

The issue I'm facing is the last parameter `ces_ssn` can sometimes be anything like `ces_fw` or `adv_let` so I can't entirely set an endIndex in my code.

Is there a way to create a function that is dynamic in saying just give me the first 32 characters every time, not matter the endIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for **Swift 4**

```
var url = "http://fools.sayers.mine.cs/api/analytics/ces_ssn"
let newStr = url.prefix(32)
```

or probably the perfect way

```
if let index = url.range(of: "api/")?.upperBound {
    let api = url.prefix(upTo: index)
}
```

Comment: yeesh do I feel dumb right now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a URL. Use `URL`. Assuming you know you want to drop the last two parts of the path, you can do:

```
let myURL = URL(string: "http://fools.sayers.mine.cs/api/analytics/ces_ssn")!
let shortURL = myURL.deletingLastPathComponent().deletingLastPathComponent()
print(shortURL)
```

Output:

> http://fools.sayers.mine.cs/api/

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefix()

```
"http://fools.sayers.mine.cs/api/analytics/ces_ssn".prefix(32)
```

Answer (score -1):

That sounds prone to mistake if all of a sudden your URL is `https` instead of `http`, for example.

Instead I would do:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://fools.sayers.mine.cs/api/analytics/ces_ssn")!
let components = url.pathComponents
let scheme = url.scheme!
let host = url.host!
let slash = components.removeFirst()
print (components) // ["api", "analytics", "ces_ssn"]
```

The components you are interested in are then the 0 and 1 component, and you could reconstruct your URL like this:

```
let newURL = "\(scheme)://\(host)/\(components[0])/\(components[1])"
print (newURL) // "http://fools.sayers.mine.cs/api/analytics"
```